# Exit function in PHP exit(9)

Tags: php, function, exit

In PHP I often exit from the program using exit(0). Also, exit(1) means there is an error. In fact, any number other than 0 indicates an error. So, if I use exit(9) - is their any significance of numbers greater than zero or it is immaterial. PHP manual from php.net shows exit(0376) as octal.

Comment: If you are running this in the CLI the exit code number can be tested in a batch/bash script to decide what to do with a specific error. Otherwise it makes very little difference

Comment: The exit code is returned to the program which started PHP. One can use it to know the nature of the error if PHP didn't exit cleanly (with 0).